# How we send mail in php (core php) from localhost using wamp

Tags: php, email, localhost, wamp

I want to send mail from my local host in any live mail box (Google. yahoo etc). I am in windows environment and using wamp. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do without a library. Make use of [`PHPMailer`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

How to configure **`PHPMailer`** on **`WAMP`**. See [`this`](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,39412,40970)

Comment: Of course he can do that without library. It'll be harder (because he have to write much more code) but definitely possible.

Comment: Well yes. When i read this `I am new in php` , I wanna make things easy for him first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sendmail for this and
for wamp local host you could make some change in php.ini file, as

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = yourmail@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
//just remove semicolon

sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

Now restart your apache